# Python Plot Bar Chart Summing a Column, Grouped by Two Different Columns

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data set:

```
Year Month Category Count Line
2019   1       a      2    5
2019   2       b      5    7
2018   1       a      7    12
```

I want to plot a bar chart in chronological order where the y axis is a sum of the Count field and there is a separate secondary axis for the Line column (no sum).

I am having trouble creating that group and sum.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['SumCount'] = df.groupby('Year')['Count'].transform('sum')
ax=df.plot(kind='bar', x='Year',y='Line', alpha=.7, color='g', position=1, width =.2)
df.plot(kind='bar', x='Year',y='SumCount', ax=ax, secondary_y=True, alpha=.8, position=0, width=.2)
```

Output:

[image]